# Paperclip not saving file and attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

This i my application: https://github.com/MagdalenaL/harcerki
I have a problem with Paperclip. It isn't save any file and attachment to database. I read all the posts on this topic but none helped me. I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: In which model you wants to add the attachment, I have checked your code but no one has the lines which required in the paperclip configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were talking about the avatar in products.rb.

You are missing avatar in the strong parameters of the related controller:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:avatar, :name, :number, :image, :availability, :prize, :status, :edition)
```

EDIT : I've read your code more in detail, and there is something you don't understand about the MVC model.

You're supposed to put in your models only the list of fields/attributes you have (I don't like ActiveRecord for this reason, because these fields are "hidden" inside your database schema, unlike Mongoid)

The controller are what links the Views (the HTML the user sees) and the models. Because a user could at any time modify the POST request sent by his browser, since Rails 4 "strong parameters" have become the default option. Basically, you have to explicitely tell your application what form parameters are allowed, so a malicious user cannot, for example, set a `:superadmin` column to true for his user.

Therefore, lines like

```
def product_params
params.require(:product).permit(:avatar)
end
```

have absolutely no meaning inside your models. They should be in your controller only.

`params` is the name of the variable that contains the POST parameters sent by a user.